# Converting an Integer to a Text Value in Power BI

Tags: powerbi, dax, m

I’m creating a **calculated column** in a Power BI report. The calculated column concatenates **integer** and **text** columns. I tried using the below query to accomplish this, but it resulted in a syntax error.

```
CalculatedColumn = Number.ToText(table1.[RegionID]) & " " &  table1.[RegionName]
```

I tried some other conversion methods also, which were not successful. Could someone please guide me on how one could achieve the above objective in Power BI?

Comment: Why do you need to convert at all?  You should be able to do: `= table1.[RegionID] & " " &  table1.[RegionName]`

Answer (score 10, accepted):

Make sure you have the correct format string.

Try this:

`= FORMAT(table1.[RegionID], "#") & " " &  table1.[RegionName]`

Answer (score 20):

Try

```
= "Text" & Number.ToText(Number)
```

Answer (score 10):

You must use the function format. The first argument is the value itself, and the second one is the format you want. Use "string", like the code below:

```
=FORMAT([RegionID], "string") & " " & [RegionName]
```

Comment: I am using FORMAT([Year], "string") on an integer year field and always get "0tri0g"

Comment: Try `FORMAT([RegionID], "")` insted of `FORMAT([RegionID], "string")`

Answer (score 4):

`=FORMAT(numeric_value, string_format)` recognises nine formats for the second argument of `=FORMAT()`, where the type of string format is specified. The *0tri0g* error referred to above arises because `string` itself isn't one of the nine formats. You can see the full list here: https://msdn.microsoft.com/query-bi/dax/pre-defined-numeric-formats-for-the-format-function.

In the original case here, you'd use `=FORMAT([Year], "General Number"]` to return a year as a four-digit number, stored as text.

Answer (score 0):

I have created the `calculated column` as below without any `explicit` `conversion`:

```
Region = table1.[RegionID] + " " + table1.[RegionName]
```

Comment: If you use this method, you may run into problems trying to '+' (it's not a number).  User '&' - for strings instead.

Answer (score 0):

You can use the FORMAT keyword as stated the the above comments.

Just make sure if concatenating strings, use the '&' not '+'.
If you still get errors, use format.

```
Region = FORMAT(table1.[RegionID], "#") & " " & table1.[RegionName]
```

You can use "string" instead of "#" too.